# Hover and Focus Jquery Combine for dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to figure this out. I've seen this code here about combining .hover() and .focus(). Unfortunately I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
$('ul.nav li.dropdown').on("mouseenter focus mouseleave",
    function(event) {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(100).fadeIn(200);
    }, function() {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(100).fadeOut(200);
    });
```

Comment: `Unfortunately I don't know what I'm doing wrong.`. Neither do we. What happens? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry... On mouse-over, the menu should drop down or if the user is using a screen reader, on focus the menu should drop down... my original code for focus looked like this:   $('ul.nav li.dropdown').focus(function() { ..

Comment: Can you please add the `HTML` also or even better, make a working snippet that shows the problem?